# Transfer a wordpress site from subfolder to the main domain path

Tags: hosting

I am using godaddy.

I have this subfolder here: http://www.iliveaccountable.com/mytestsite/

where we run our test dev site and we want to transfer it to the main URL http://www.iliveaccountable.com/ replacing the old site.

We already backup this site from a cloned path but wondering HOW we could to transfer the test dev site to the main URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have following two option to transfer your Wordpress website from test to main URL

[1] You take full backup of http://www.iliveaccountable.com/mytestsite/ along with database if any, and copy with your local system

[2] Remove sub-folder../mytestsite/

[3] Install Wordpress with main site folder[www.iliveaccountable.com] and upload web-content to make your site live

OR

[1] Write redirection rule with your .htaccess file which points your main site to test site.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the tutorials shown as below.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/329-move-folders
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/moving-wordpress-moving-your-site-from-a-subdirectory-to-the-root-directory--cms-22848